# Can Websocket able to receive data from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, websocket

I am trying to building a php and html5 websocket chat system where one end will be socket and other end will be ajax. Is it possible PHP's socket_recv() function receive data from ajax/mysql or from any other source(which is not send by "send" method or socket)?

** We want one end in ajax because still websocket is not supported by all browser specially IE.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use WebSockets on the client end, you don't need them on the server side either. (Indeed, you **can't** use them unless both parties support them.) AJAX creates normal HTTP requests; you can handle them just like any other request in PHP.

Also, critically: the PHP `socket_` functions are raw TCP/UDP sockets, **not** WebSockets. The WebSocket protocol is considerably more complicated than they support directly. PHP sockets can be used in the process of *implementing* WebSockets, but it's much better to use a library like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) which has already done the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Ratchet also uses websocket, so it will not work in IE. If Websocket not support in one end, I am planning to use ajax in both end (long polling)

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Ratchet supports web-socket-js, which is a polyfill for older browsers.  You can find more info here: http://socketo.me/docs/flash